# glusterfs heketi use partition instead raw device to permit easy extension

Tags: kubernetes, glusterfs

I have create a gluster cluster to provisioning disk to kubernetes, but my question is focused on the heketi and gluster.

we run the cluster in a virtual environment so the disk presented to the VMs could be expanded due they are virtual disk.

We expand the disk and try to let gluster cluster to see the new dimension of the device with `heketi-cli device resync $id` after this command completed successfully the cluster continue to see the device with his original dimension; 
after searching a while this seems to be a normal behavior for heketi (I found a fork seem to do this, but I prefer to work with the official release).

So I was thinking as "workaround" of this limitation to partition the disk and give in the topology file the partition instead the RAW device, I add it and apparently seems work.

So, could I encounter any issues on this configuration? 
Some body could explain why the raw device is suggested?

As I far as I know the PhisicalVolume on LVM is suggested to be created on top of a partition to permit the expansion of the disk instead always adding disks. (off course in an environment with a storage which provide disk or VirtualEnvironment were disk could be expanded.)